RL parallel circuit

This problem is available on MIT coursware assignements 9.
Knowing that I(t)=4-10u(t) mA; R=1 kOhm; L=1 mH
I want to find:
a)IL(t=3.00E-06 s)
b)V( t=3.57E-07 s)
c)IR(t=1.90E-06 s)
V is the voltage at the inductors terminals. I can't understand if u(t) is also the voltage on the inductors terminals and I don't know how to find the expressions for the diferent currents and voltages.
I started with I=IL+IR; IR=V/R; V=L.dIL/dt
I made the substitutions on the first equation geting
4-10V=V/R+IL<=>dIL/dt+IL/(L(10+1/R))=4/(L(10+1/R))
After solving the diferential equation I get IL=4mA which is wrong since the current should be a function of time and so I can't move from here.

u(t) is the Heaviside step function. Since I has a dc component, L will have an initial condition of 4mA. The MIT courseware should help with this 1st Order differential equation.
